# RTK-codegen-openapi -- Add formData flag on generation of endpoints usting RTK query and codegen-openapi

Tags: rtk-query, codegen

While using `@rtk-query/codegen-openapi` for API query generation, I've encountered a specific requirement for file upload endpoints. To accommodate file uploads using formData, it's necessary to include the `formData: true` flag within the query. is there any configuration option exists to automatically integrate this flag into the generated endpoints?

```js
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    uploadFile: build.mutation<
      UploadFileResponse,
      UploadFileArg
    >({
      query: (queryArg) => ({
        url: `/files/upload`,
        method: "POST",
        body: queryArg,
        formData: true // need to add this flag on selected endpoints
      }),
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?